# Does LDAP work within just one directory or diferent directories can comunicate each other using LDAP?

Tags: ldap, directory

I started to learn about directories just a month ago and this question came to my midn. I know that LDAP is an open protocol that defines services within a directory. But I asked myself if there is possible having two different implemented directories and use LDAP to communicate each other? Does it has sense? Is there any scenario where this can happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple directory servers can communicate together. The most frequent case is when you are using a multi-master replication topology. Changes that go either side are propagated to the other side, commonly with using the ldap protocol. e.g. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-asid-ldap-mult-mast-rep-02

Another case is when you are using a front end (e.g. a directory proxy server, virtual directory) that present a subset / combination of multiple underlying directories.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, an common example is merging of 2 companies, each on having it's own directory -> enable cross-directory authentication, email services etc..

I have the case of a client that use MS Active Directory for Windows servers and openldap for everything else (hundreds of Linux servers, network equipments...).
They are linked together to allow single authentication.